# Rails 3 Routing: I have "/products?cat=1", I want "/art"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I'm fairly new to Rails and find myself confused by the routing config.

In my project I have 2 models: Product and Category. Product belongs_to Category, Category has_many Product.

The Products controller has an index action which takes an optional `cat` param. When present, the `cat` param filters the list of products to ones within that category. Pretty basic stuff.

What I *want* is for `mysite.com/art` to have the same result as `mysite.com/products?cat=1`, where "art" is the slug for category 1. I have several other resourceful routes defined, including one for products:

```
resources :products do
  collection do
    get 'search_by_color'
  end
end
```

I also want to point `/products/some-product-slug` at `products#show`

I'm using Rails 3. How can I make this routing set-up happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your categories are static and the slugs never change, what you're asking for probably is not advisable. That's because there's no way to statically tell the difference between `/art` and, say, `/about`, or `/contact`, etc. It's also not very RESTful and is therefore frowned upon somewhat by Rails.

That said, if you want to do it anyway, you should write a *request constraint*. This is any object that responds to `matches?` and accepts a single argument (the request to match). If it returns true, the route will match and it will be routed in the way you specify. For example, you might write something like:

```
match '/:category_slug' => 'products#index',
  :constraints => CategorySlugConstraint.new

class CategorySlugConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    Category.find_by_slug ...
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks john. so in this example I'd be able to access the `category_slug` with `params[:category_slug]`?

Comment: CategorySlugConstraint.new returns an error for me: `TypeError (Cannot visit ActionDispatch::Request): config/routes.rb:53:in matches?'`. removing the `.new` resolves it.